# I want to know price for local listing

Tags: seo, local-seo

I would like to get listing from some of local listing so I want to know about that price for listing to their internet sites?
this is my list :

1   Info group

```
2.Axiom

3.Starkness/Localize

4.Factual

5.Foursquare

6.Super pages

7.Best of the Web
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, make sure you do want to pay for this and why. If it is just to get your business description, and a link, chances are this is not worth it.

You can use a service like yext, to scan many different websites for links to your site. then you can either pay them to create listings for you, including some of the sites you mentioned, or google and visit those sites, then creating accouts manually. Takes some time, but there's really no point in paying just for a link.

Take a look [here.](http://www.yext.com/)

1 - Info group and [express update](http://www.expressupdate.com/search) are part of the same group. By visiting their site you can claim profiless in many different ones for free.

2 - Don't know Axiom.

3 - Also don't know this one.

4 - Factual is free, just create an account and list your business. You can also request downloads of business data, and chances are if its in a small location, they will even give you that for free =]

5 - Foursquare is free.

6 - Superpages has both, free basic listing and a paid one. You would have to contact them because they offer a lot more than just a business listing on a site.

7 - Best of the web is also paid for but I could not find pricing information.

Comment: @Neel not a problem, glad to help.